Parametrize table name in SQL query
I have a Python script executing DB2 query as
select count(*) as num_rows from {table}
The value of {table} is read from a list of tables and I need to print out the count corresponding to each table. However that SQL statement is reported for SQL injection vulnerability. Now I can parameterize the value part of a SQL statement, but how do I take tablename as a parameter to resolve the SQL injection issue?
I tried filtering the "table" input using shlex as
table = shlex.quote(table) 
and then passing it on to the SQL query but it doesn't help

I'd just make sure that table comes from a whitelist of names, and ignore this particular warning in the vulnerability report.

Having an allowed list of tablenames is slightly impractical, since there are hundreds of tables in the database. It will make the code look ugly

the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example

@Muradin If the value of table comes from an internal list, not from user-supplied data, then this is effectively whitelisted already. SQL injection should not be possible.

shlex.quote() is for shell commands, not SQL.

If you have 500 tables, create 500 queries, pick the one you need and run it. Bye-bye SQL Injection.

SQL does not allow table names to be parameters. Tables, like any identifiers, keywords, and other syntax, must be fixed in the query at the time it is parsed, which is before parameters are sent.
Parameters can only be used in the same way that a literal value is. Parameters are not just string substitution. They are combined with the SQL query after parsing. That's why parameters protect against SQL injection — the content of the parameter cannot affect the SQL query syntax, because once the query has been parsed, the parameter can only be used as a scalar value.
So you have to format your SQL query with table names before parsing. You're doing it correctly using an f-string:
sql = f"select count(*) as num_rows from {table}"

This means that it's up to you to make sure {table} is safe. That is, the value of that variable must not be based on any untrusted source.
Most often this is user input, but it can be any other source that might include content out of your control. E.g. it could be read from a file, or fetched from a web service, or even read from string data in your own database.
Basically, the only truly safe content is that which is based on static values defined in your code.
Some SQL injection defense allows filtering, for example:

Comparing a table name to a fixed list defined in your code. This is the 'whitelist' that was mentioned in the comments above.
You responded that this is inconvenient if you have hundreds of
tables, but I suggest that you don't need the list to contain every
table in your database, just the tables that are valid to use in the
specific SQL query.
If you really need the query to be used against any table, that's
kind of an outlier case, so you shouldn't be surprised that it takes
extra code.

Comparing the table name to list of known table names you fetch from the metadata of your database server.

Validating the table name against a pattern, e.g. a regular expression.


Any method that is strict enough to reject arbitrary content should be sufficient.
You also need to delimit the table name, just in case you have a real table that contains whitespace or special characters, or if it conflicts with an SQL reserved word. So properly you should put the identifier in SQL double-quotes. I would recommend using triple-quoted f-strings, so you can use double-quotes freely:
sql = f"""
  select count(*) as num_rows from "{table}"
"""

You'd still have to ensure the table name doesn't contain a literal " character, because that would imbalance the quotes.
